# Typescript ES2022 function call

Tags: javascript, typescript, es2022

Out of curiosity I checked the generated javascript with typescript target configured to ES2022 and I saw something like this:

```
function leFormat(a) { console.log(`yes`, a) }
(0, leFormat)(new Date())
```

Why typescript chooses to do this?
Why not just?:

```
leFormat(new Date())
```

Also, between parentheses values separated by comma will return the last one

```
a = (0, 1, '', null, console.log, undefined) // a === undefined
typeof (0, 1, '', null, console.log, undefined) === 'object'
(0, 1, '', null, console.log, undefined).toString() // TypeError: undefined has no properties
```

Is there a use for this, or is it just a quirk of the language?